# How to cancel a running query from UI in stateless Programming

Tags: thymeleaf, prepared-statement

I am converting a client application from java swing to a spring boot application that will run on a server.  On the UI of the swing app there is a query interface that users can click cancel if they want to cancel the query.  If they click that button it basically does a preparedStatement.cancel().  How can I mimic this same behavior on a UI that is using Spring and thymeleaf?

The problem that I am running into, is that I am unable to find a way transfer the prepared statement from the Java Code to the UI.

Thanks in advance!
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be transferring the `PreparedStatement` to the ui.  Instead, you should either user ajax (or a form submission) to cancel the statement on the server.

Comment: That would be ideal, but how can I know which statement to cancel?  I do 1 ajax call to execute the statement, and another 1 to cancel it.  How would I be able to obtain that current statement started in another thread?

Comment: Well, you'll have to store the statement somewhere... on the session, probably. (Or on an application scope bean?)

Comment: Thanks!  I figure session is where I will store it, I just struggle to understand what I should/shouldn't store in session.  I just always try to put things there as a last resort.

Comment: If a user just needs to cancel their own queries, the session definitely (as a users session is only accessible to them, and you won't ever run into collisions with another users).  If a user needs to cancel another user's queries, then you'll have to do something like an application scoped bean (accessible between different sessions).    In general, I stay of way from sessions and just make applications stateless, but I don't think there is a way around this one.